# Make visible/unvisible div on click on other div

Tags: mootools, mootools-events

Can anybody help me, I need something like http://web-kreation.com/demos/login_form_mootools_1.2/, just mush simpler, when I click on one div ( login in this case) just to show other and if I click again to make unvisible. How to do that with Mootools  if I have two divs ( div id=login and div id=vis_unvis) ?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following thread to learn more how toggle element’s visibility via the javascript:

[Toggle Visibility - Show/Hide Anything](http://blog.movalog.com/a/javascript-toggle-visibility/)

Answer (score 1):

to replicate the effect in the example to it's most basic, look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/9Syj3/

```
(function() {
    var loginOpen = false, loginForm = document.id("login").set("morph", {
        link: "chain"
    }).setOpacity(0);

    document.id("toggler").addEvents({
        click: function() {
            loginForm.morph((loginOpen) ? {
                marginTop: -90,
                opacity: 0
            } : {
                marginTop: 0,
                opacity: 1
            });
            loginOpen = !loginOpen;            
            this.set("text", loginOpen ? "Hide form" : "Show form");
        }
    });
})();
```

with html of:

```
<div id="login">
This be the login form
</div>

<div id="toggler">Show form</div>
```

and css of:

```
#login {
    width: 300px;
    background: #ccc;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -90px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    z-index: 1000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 3px 3px #000;
}
```

resources for mootools: [Fx.Morph](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Fx/Fx.Morph) or the element prototype `.morph()` allows you to animate properties of an element, in this case modifying marginTop and opacity.

mootools also supports [Fx.Slide](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Slide), Fx.Reveal and more as part of the mootools-more official collection of plugins.

of course to hide/show, you could just `toggleClass` a css class which has `display: none` on the element or use [.show() / .hide()](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Element/Element.Shortcuts) or `.fade("in")` / `.fade("out")` to hide via opacity.

NO end to ways to handle this. Check Fx.Move too :)